# Set default value for attribute of struct in C

Tags: c, struct, set, default

I have a struct (in C languague) declare like below:

```
struct readyQueue
{
    int start;
    int total_CPU_burst;
    int CPU_burst;
    int CPU_bursted;
    int IO_burst;
    int CPU;
    struct readyQueue *next;
};
struct readyQueue *readyStart = NULL;
struct readyQueue *readyRear = NULL;

readyStart = mallow(sizeof(struct readyQueue) * 1);
readyRear = mallow(sizeof(struct readyQueue) * 1);
```

And I want to set readyStart->CPU = -1 , readyRead->CPU = -1, CPUchoose->CPU = -1 by default that mean if I declare new readyQueue struct like that

```
struct readyQueue *CPUchoose = NULL;
CPUchoose = mallow(sizeof(struct readyQueue) * 1);
```

Then CPUchoose->CPU also == -1, I tried to delare readyQueue like this

```
 struct readyQueue
    {
        int start;
        int total_CPU_burst;
        int CPU_burst;
        int CPU_bursted;
        int IO_burst;
        int CPU = -1;
        struct readyQueue *next;
    };
```

But when I built the code it show out an error, can anyone help me please

Comment: C does not provide "*default values*" out of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function to do it:

```
struct readyQueue* create_readyQueue()
{
    struct readyQueue* ret = malloc( sizeof( struct readyQueue ) );
    ret->CPU = -1;
    // ...
    return ret;
}

struct readyQueue* CPUchoose = create_readyQueue();
```

You have to remember to free the memory as well, so it may be better to pass in a pointer to an initialize function.

```
void init_readyQueue( struct readyQueue* q )
{
   q->CPU = -1;
   // ...
}


struct readyQueue* CPUchoose = malloc( sizeof( struct readyQueue ) );
init_readyQueue( CPUchoose );
// clearer that you are responsible for freeing the memory since you allocate it.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
struct readyQueue_s
{
   int start;
   int total_CPU_burst;
   int CPU_burst;
   int CPU_bursted;
   int IO_burst;
   int CPU;
   struct readyQueue_s *next;
}; 

struct readyQueue_s readyQueueDefault = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, NULL};    

int main(void) 
{
  struct readyQueue_s foo;

  foo = readyQueueDefault;
}
```

Read more about [initialization of structures and unions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/strin.htm).

Comment: Initialisers need to be constants. Seperate definition of `foo` and its assignment, then it would work.

Comment: What you edited was alright, the issue is with `foo`!

Comment: @alk: I think I made a mistake at the last line too since he has `readyQueue *next` in the struct itself.

Comment: @alk: there... I think its fixed now. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: Yes, 1+ for this approach.

Comment: Really should be `myReadyQueue* foo = malloc( sizeof( myReadyQueue ) ); *foo = readyQueueDefault;`

Comment: @alk: You are right. Not sure what I was thinking there.. doesn't make sense now. Fixed.

Comment: @staticx because he is asking about initializing when he `malloc`s

Comment: @clcto: Yea, but that's not what he needs to do.